# How to get display settings persistent?

Tags: multiple-monitors, laptop, display, settings

I have the following set-up:

laptop with screen:        1366x768
external LCD monitor with: 1024x768

The monitor is permanently connected and recognised by the system.
Screen is expanded to the external monitor.

But each time I login, the external monior is dark and has to be reactivated.
This also happens when the monitor is active and I log out and log in as a different user.

How can I prevent this?
Is there a way to make configuration of the monitor settings tool persistent for all users?

Comment: Which version are you on? In 12.04 at least, it is possible to apply a configuration without saving it to xorg using the GUI tool, in which case your settings aren't persistent.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!